# Problem with getJSON or PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

`Display.php`:

```
<?php
include 'sql.php';
$dataget = mysql_query("SELECT `user`,`message`,`timestamp` FROM `messages`");
$arr = array();
while ($dataarr = mysql_fetch_assoc($dataget)){
    $arr[] = $dataarr;
}
echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

`Index.php`:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.getJSON('display.php', function(data) {
            alert(data.0.user);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Trying to alert `data.0.user`.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you can't have a `.` followed by a number (save in the context of a Number). You need to use Array look-up syntax.

```
var o = {0:"foo"}
o.0 // SyntaxError
```

On the other hand:

```
var o = {0:"foo"}
console.log(o[0])//foo
```

Also, a free-standing digit followed by a `.` needs to be followed by another digit (or a non-variable character). (eg: `a0` can be followed by a `.`, as can `1`, but `1.` must be followed by a digit)

Comment: +1, but I don't understand your last statement. Because `1.` as valid as `1.0` or `1`.

Comment: @IAbstractDownvoteFactory I meant contiguous variable character

Answer (score 2):

Use `data[0].user` in your Javascript.